# How to go about app.provide in vue in case of Module Federation when I am not exposing the app.vue but a component only that is using the provided?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack-module-federation

I am providing a service using app.provide from my App.vue in the remote app. Now, that service is getting consumed by another component in the remote app, and that component I am exposing to the host. The host can't find the injected value when it consumes the remote component.
How can I get the value in the host if I am not exposing my app.vue.